# Субквадратичная сортировка

Tags: python, c++, алгоритм, сортировка

Учусь в вузе и изучаю программирование, а именно алгоритмы сортировки, и наткнулся на субквадратичную сортировку о которой нигде ничего не говорится. Может ли кто-то примерно написать в двух словах в чем ее суть и привести пример кода? Буду очень сильно благодарен.

Comment: именно субквадратичная, а не квадратичная?

Comment: чет я такую первый раз слышу...

Comment: [Субквадратичное_время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)

Answer (score 6):

Думаю имеется в виду не конкретный алгоритм, а любые алгоритмы сортировки со сложностью меньше квадратичной. Где-то их еще называют "улучшенные алгоритмы сортировки".

Comment: Например, [Shell sort](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0)

Comment: Лучше уж сортировку за линейное время, она быстрее.